# Access Sqlite database in background while data protection is on for app

Tags: sqlite, ios7, data-protection

Can we access the Sqlite database in background while data protection is on for the app. If the data protection is on for the app then the file system is not accessible. Can app write to database in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite database is not accessible when complete data protection is on. From  [apple web site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html)

> While the user’s device is locked, protected files are inaccessible even to the app that created them.